# Editing CSV column data in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a column in a CSV devoted to authors of literary works. They are entered in the standard Library of Congress format: LastName FirstName BirthYear-DeathYear. There are exceptions however, especially with female names and unknown dates.

So the author column may contain entries like this:

```
Pope Alexander 1688-1744
Barbauld Mrs. (Anna Laetitia) 1743-1825
Aylett Robert 1583-1655?
Higden Ranulf d. 1364.
```

What I would like to do is isolate only the first name of the authors in a vector. As a beginner, I am still a bit rough on the pre-processing/preparation stage of data in R, and am at a loss when it comes trying to cut down text when it is in a) more than one instance and b) has several exceptions that must be accounted for.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: So the comma will be cause the `LastName` to be separated out into a new column. The `FirstName` can be split from the date by using `strsplit`, where you hand it the vector containing `FirstName` and the dates, and it splits based on a space character. strsplit(x, ". "), for instance, would split vector `x` after each space.

Comment: Is there really no comma after `Alexander` and other first names?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. And revisiting the csv, it seems there are not even commas between last names (I edited the sample accordingly). This, I imagine, is so that the CSV doesn't separate the last name from the first as Tad Dallas assumed.

Comment: The length and number of people's full names is virtually impossible to standardize given the number of names people have and are allowed to have, etc.